# Wrap button in `{% buttons %}`

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I learns the button from bootstrap with Django template

```
{% buttons %}
   <button name="button" class="btn btn-primary">log in</button>
{% endbuttons %}
```

I test it make no difference when removing {%%}

```
<button name="button" class="btn btn-primary">log in</button>
```

What's the reason the button should be wrapedin {% buttons %}

Comment: Never seen that template variable before. Do you have a source?

Comment: where your `{% buttons %}` from ? is there any 3rd party library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of reason is using third-party package, like [django-bootstrap3](http://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html?highlight=button)  .

And in this document, it use Template tags like `{% buttons %}` to wrap the button, and let button use bootstrap3.

```
{% buttons %}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Submit
</button>
{% endbuttons %}
```